# why i see Call to undefined method Error?

Tags: laravel

im learning laravel so if im not  well as you are accept my apologies...
my problem is when i try to define a new method in web.php i got error!some times phpstorm sets problem on 'Route'word so i can run my blade pages but sometimes it sets problem on 'get','post','group' ,...and i cant run my app
ill show you how i defined my routes

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'] ,function (){
    Route::get('/users','UsersController@index');
});
```

after all this my point is making a controller so i got this error to fix so i can move on...

Comment: can u post an image of the error you see please?

Comment: You don't need the `use Illuminate\Routing\Route;` import as `Route` is already available in the routes files. Your IDE shows an error probably because you are missing some plugins to work with Laravel. Install this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532-laravel/

Comment: remove this unnecessary import `use Illuminate\Routing\Route;` as it is not required

Comment: @AshleyBrown i'v got this problem was unnecessary import of Route

Comment: @nakov it worked thanks ,about that plugin i've installed it before but now i can run app but IDE says Route is undefined class and suggests importing it ...is it ok?

Comment: @SalmanZafar thanks alot yes it worked با تشکر فراوان

Answer (score 0):

Named groups in laravel

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admins','as'=>'admin.'], function(){
    Route::get('users', ['as' => 'user', 'uses' = > 'UsersController@index']);
});
```

Also make sure you have `index` method in your `UsersController`.

FYR :- https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-5-1-names-for-route-groups/

Comment: thanks for your reply it was from unnecessary import of Route